# How to open webview in Blackberry?

Tags: browser, blackberry, webview

How to open link in webview in Blackberry like iPhone and Android ?

Which should not be open in Browser ,it should be opening in Webview through application .

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5661777/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Blackberry equivalent of a WebView is a [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/package-summary.html). Example code from [this page](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Browser_field_1184788_11.jsp):

```
import net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;

public class BrowserFieldDemo extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BrowserFieldDemo app = new BrowserFieldDemo();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public BrowserFieldDemo()
    {
        pushScreen(new BrowserFieldDemoScreen());
    }
}

class BrowserFieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public BrowserFieldDemoScreen()
    {
        BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

        add(browserField);
        browserField.requestContent("http://www.blackberry.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx core its working nice. but i cant zoom on particular site page .is it possible in this ?

Comment: Maybe try working with some of the options in [BrowserFieldConfig](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldConfig.html).

Comment: this is just for the java file, right?...what about the xml file?...how is this displayed? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Options Icon -> Host Routing Tables -> Register Now

If the above instructions failed, try stepping through these instructions one by one

```
* Try getting your service books retransmitted.
  a. Login to your BlackBerry Web Client (BWC/BIS) site.
  b. Click "Profiles" (At the top of your BWC webpage via your PC)
  c. Click "Send Internet Browser Service Book"
* Try rebooting your BlackBerry by removing and reinserting battery.
* Make sure you are running BlackBerryOS 4.0 by checking:
  Check Options -> About
  If you are not running at least Version 4.0, you need to download and install BlackBerryOS 4.0 then repeating all the above instructions again.
* If that does not work, and you are on a BlackBerry Enterprise Server (BES), try re-activating your BlackBerry on BES. This may be as simple as connecting your BlackBerry to your PC and synchronizing your BlackBerry while Outlook is in ONLINE mode.
```

Comment: thanx Alfred .but i want to open particular site through application which is not open through device Browser .so what can i do for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for the [BrowserField UI component](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Browser_field_1184788_11.jsp).